# jQuery var or PHP

Tags: php, jquery, variables

This is probably quite easy but Im stuck.. I have a price in a span tag and Im using the following to get the price and display it on the page:

```
var cost = $(this).find('span').html();
$('#cost').html('Value ' + cost);
```

Now I need to also pass that cost to the value="" in a hidden form input tag:

```
<input id="amount" type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
```

But I cant figure out how to pass the cost var to the value. Should I be using jQuery for this or should I pass it PHP and then echo it?

Thanks

Comment: @CodingAnt you can't use `.html()` on an input element

Comment: @DannyHearnah: yes you can.

Comment: @Glavić trying to change the value of an input field with `.html()` does not work.

Comment: @DannyHearnah: that is true, but statement you wrote `you can't use .html() on an input element` is NOT true. You CAN use `.html()` on input field.

Comment: @Glavić - brilliant, I thought the point you were making was petty. using `.html()` will not effect the `input` element what-so-ever, so for all intent and purposes my statement was correct. `.html()` uses `.innerHTML`, which only effects elements which can contain HTML

Comment: @DannyHearnah: again, you are wrong with statement: `using .html() will not effect the input element what-so-ever`. It will! If you run `$('input').html('html');` all inputs will be changed to `<input...>html</input>`. But ok, I'm smartass, just try it yourself.

Comment: @giorgio: if being smartass is when correcting people of wrong, then I hope any1 will be smartass with me when I will be wrong, and would correct me. And there is no need to be rude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need AJAX or PHP, simply use:

```
$('#amount').val(cost);
```

As you are getting `cost` directly.

Comment: So simple thanks. And yes, I must read up on .val. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$('#amount').val(cost);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jquery, just do this:

```
$("#amount").val(cost)
```

Also, you might want to read up on jquery a bit more: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
$('#amount').val(cost);
```

Refer to [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)